# I have certificate file with ".p12" extension, Can i use it as keystore file for SSL authentication?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore

Hi We are calling a webservice from an ETL tool and which worked fine in SOAP UI, But when we use in our ETL tool it throws an error of "INvalid keystore format". So the question is can we use the certificate file as keystore file for SSL authentication, Or are those completely different?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to jks like this

keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS